# I am wondering if my ER model is good

Tags: model, entity-relationship

I would be really eppreciated if you can tell me if my ER model is good. What's batter for Author table to be in separated table or in Book table?[ER model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y75kx.png)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: An author can write many books, and a book can be written by multiple authors, so Author should almost certainly be distinct from Book. In your diagram you associated Book directly with Copy without using a relationship - this isn't valid in the ER model.

Comment: I am confused on how to join BOOK and AUTHOR tables together (using JOIN). I need to create FK_ISBN in AUTHOR table right?

Comment: I would recommend a many-to-many relationship between `BOOK` and `AUTHOR`, e.g. `WROTE (ISBN PK/FK, Author ID PK/FK)`. If you add an `ISBN` FK to the `AUTHOR` table, you'll only be able to associate one book with each author.

Comment: I am really new to this and still learning but, isnt that you  can't have many-to-many relationship in relation model?

Comment: I am so cofused with all that straings, querys...

Comment: The relational model has no problem handling many-to-many binary relationships, as well as ternary and higher relationships. It's the old network data model which can't handle anything but the simplest relationships.

Comment: Can you please tell me the xhole string for joining those tables? sorry i am really lost here :)

Comment: Assuming the `WROTE` relationship I suggested in my 2nd comment, you could join all 3 tables like so: `SELECT * FROM Author INNER JOIN Wrote ON Author.Author_ID = Wrote.Author_ID INNER JOIN Book ON Wrote.ISBN = Book.ISBN`

Comment: aaahh thank you sooo much :) YEA i see now! hehe :)

Comment: I added our conversation as my answer so we can resolve this question if you're satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

An author can write many books, and a book can be written by multiple authors, so Author should almost certainly be distinct from Book. In your diagram you associated Book directly with Copy and Author without using relationships - this isn't valid in the ER model.

> I am confused on how to join BOOK and AUTHOR tables together (using JOIN). I need to create FK_ISBN in AUTHOR table right?

I would recommend a many-to-many relationship between BOOK and AUTHOR, e.g. `WROTE (ISBN PK/FK, Author ID PK/FK)`. If you add an ISBN FK to the AUTHOR table, you'll only be able to associate one book with each author.

> I am really new to this and still learning but, isnt that you can't have many-to-many relationship in relation model?

The relational model has no problem handling many-to-many binary relationships, as well as ternary and higher relationships. It's the old network data model that can't handle anything but the simplest relationships.

> Can you please tell me the whole string for joining those tables?

Assuming the WROTE relationship I suggested in my 2nd comment, you could join all 3 tables like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM Author
INNER JOIN Wrote ON Author.Author_ID = Wrote.Author_ID
INNER JOIN Book ON Wrote.ISBN = Book.ISBN
```

Answer (score 0):

I made relational model in MySQL. Is it ok?
[Relational model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Osz1.png)

Comment: Please for quick response

Comment: I want to know if relational model is ok and I can continue my work...if someone can help